# Creating a single set up for chrome, safari, firefox and IE extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon, bho, safari-extension

I have built an extension for all four major browsers like firefox(.xpi), chrome(.crx),
safari(.safariextz) and IE(.exe). I am able to install these extension separately. But I need one setup for all four extension. Can anybody guide me how to create one setup project for all four extensions?

Comment: You could use the browser user-agent string and serve the appropriate link for the user's browser.

Comment: i have done it already on my website. but i want to create an exe so that when user runs that exe. all four extension get installed on his browsers.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon: That would be a very bad idea even for installation from a website - don't do browser sniffing, do feature sniffing. The installation from a website is JavaScript-assisted in any case, so one can check whether things like `InstallTrigger` or `chrome.webstore` exist.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I didn't know that. Why is browser sniffing considered bad practice?

Comment: pagerage.com already doing this type of thing. they have PagerageSetup which installs addons on browsers.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon Browser sniffing relies on user agent strings which a) change constantly and b) are user configurable. Feature sniffing is much more secure and less likely to break should a new browser version change the useragent string.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon: Because Firefox isn't the only browser implementing `InstallTrigger` (e.g. SeaMonkey does as well) and Chrome isn't the only browser implementing `chrome.webstore` (Chromium, Iron do as well). Plus what Bulk said.

Comment: @(Bulk, Wladimir Palant) thanks!

Comment: Why just exe too? What about other Operating Systems?

Comment: currently i am just thinking about windows. later i will think about other operations systems.

Comment: @AndrewHall - have you got any idea how can i do this type of thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use any kind of installer to perform this task.

On Windows I use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) it has functions/plugins that allow you to write to registries, manipulate files, detect Browser versions etc. Which are basically the only things you need to install a browser extension